# No shutodown on reboot in Freebsd12, Rasp3

Tags: pi-3, freebsd

I have installed Freebsd12 on a sd card and 
put it in a Raspberry3. 
The image I am using is the first one on [this page](http://www.raspbsd.org/raspberrypi.html)

I have this problem, when I give the #> reboot
command services go down but the machine does not
do the power-down/power-up cycle.

I am giving power to the Rasp via USB.

Any suggestion ?